# i'm not understanding where i did the mistake

Tags: python

problem:
For this problem, we'll round an int value up to the next multiple of 10 if its rightmost digit is 5 or more, so 15 rounds up to 20. Alternately, round down to the previous multiple of 10 if its rightmost digit is less than 5, so 12 rounds down to 10. Given 3 ints, a b c, return the sum of their rounded values. To avoid code repetition, write a separate helper "def round10(num):" and call it 3 times. Write the helper entirely below and at the same indent level as round_sum().

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
round_sum(16, 17, 18) → 60
round_sum(12, 13, 14) → 30
round_sum(6, 4, 4) → 10
```

my code:

```
def round_sum(a, b, c):
 round10(a)
 round10(b)
 round10(c)
 
 return a+b+c

def round10(num):
  if num%10>=5:
    while num%10!=0:
      num = num+1
  else:
    while num%10!=0:
      num = num-1
```

[enter link description here](https://codingbat.com/prob/p179960)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, your title should be a concise summary of your problem so other users can decide whether they can help (or learn). Your does not do that at all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't modify `a,b,c`. `round10` computes the value you want but since you don't keep it in any variable it's forgotten immediately. Try this:

```
def round_sum(a, b, c):
 a = round10(a)
 b = round10(b)
 c = round10(c)
 
 return a+b+c
```

also `round10` needs to return your final value:

```
def round10(num):
  if num%10>=5:
    while num%10!=0:
      num = num+1
  else:
    while num%10!=0:
      num = num-1
  return num # <----
```

Answer (score 0):

My Code

```
def round_sum(a, b, c):
  count = 0
  for i in (a,b,c):
    if i<5: i = 0
    if i>4 and i<10: i = 10
    if i%10 in [5,6,7,8,9]and i!= 0 and i > 9:
      i = i + (10-i%10)
    elif i%10 in [1,2,3,4] and i!=0 and i > 9:
      i = i - (i%10)
    count = count + i
  return count
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not help explain the mistake in OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def roundsum(a, b, c):
    sum=0

    for x in (a,b,c):
        if 5<=x<=10:
           y=x-x+10
           sum+=y
        elif x>10:
            if x%10<5:
                y=x-(x%10)
                sum+=y
            elif x%10>=5:
                y=x-(x%10)+10
                sum+=y

    return sum
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).